# Python 2.7 AWS Lambda Support will end in 2020?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

With the end of life of Python 2.7 will I still be able to deploy code using this version in AWS Lambda? 
When should I migrate my functions to 3.6?

I coudn't find anything from AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented at [Runtime Support Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html).

Specifically, [Python 2.7 will be EOL on 2020-01-01](https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches). AWS will typically notify you 60 days in advance of a runtime deprecation. Upon deprecation, you can update an existing Lambda function for 30 days but you can't create new Lambda functions using that runtime. The Lambda function and its deprecated runtime environment will still be available for execution.

I would plan to migrate functions before the Python 2.7 EOL date.

Comment: thank you jarmod! I've not been using AWS for a long time and I was worried about it.

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is a little misleading. On 2020-01-02, AWS [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continued-support-for-python-2-7-on-aws-lambda/) it would continue to run Python 2 scripts until the end of calendar 2020. The pertinent part of their post:

> We recognize that Python 2 and 3 differ across several core language aspects, and the application binary interface is not always compatible. We also recognize that these differences can make migration challenging. To allow you additional time to prepare, AWS Lambda will continue to provide critical security patches for the Python 2.7 runtime until at least December 31, 2020. Lambda’s scope of support includes the Python interpreter and standard library, but does not extend to third-party packages.

So you should migrate functions, but you have the rest of this calendar year.

**edit**: The linked AWS blog post is updated and the new end-of-support date is June 1, 2021.